# Objective c, changing NSString property using buttons tap

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, button

I have a view: "myView" , 3 buttons in this view with title:"myButton1","myButton2" and 3... and a property in myView, NSString: "myString". How can i do this: When I press this button I want to change myString in buttons title property("button1..2,3").

Comment: Get the action for the button press and then just set the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *btn1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *btn3=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


}
-(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton*)sender{

[sender setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `myView` is either the view of a `UIViewController` (i.e. accessible through `myViewController.view`) or it is one of its subviews / subsubview etc.

---

**If you are using Interface Builder** to create your view controller (e.g. in a storyboard) you can open the assistant editor

(click the icon [image: assistant editor] in the upper right corner)

and drag a line from each button to your viewController.h file (hold CTRL and drag to the source code in the lower window).

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Select 'Action' as connection type and give each method a unique name like `buttoniTapped`. Open the viewController.c file in the editor. There you should find the newly created action methods. Now make those methods change your string:

```
- (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
    self.myView.myString = @"Button 1 was tapped.";
}

- (IBAction)button2Tapped:(id)sender {
    self.myView.myString = @"Button 2 was tapped.";
}

- (IBAction)button3Tapped:(id)sender {
    self.myView.myString = @"Button 3 was tapped.";
}
```

(This will only work if you create a property `myView` in `myViewController` for the view that contains the three buttons.)

---

Generally I think it is a better idea to make `myString` a property of the view controller rather than the view because it makes things easier and separates your data from your view.